# Get an unknown key name from Firebase function database trigger

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Firebase functions and trying to understand how to get a certain key from the database .onCreate trigger. Here is an example:

```
exports.createUserRoundData = 
functions.database.ref('/data/players/{user_key}/').onCreate(event => {

    var eventData = event.data.val();

    var userKey = event.params.user_key;

    var itemKey = eventData.items; // This returns an object

});
```

The structure is:

```
players > user_key > items > item_key > data
```

In the above scenario how can I retrieve the item_key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can,

You need something like this :

```
exports.createUserRoundData = functions.database.ref('/data/players/{user_key}/').onCreate(event => {
    var userKey = event.params.user_key; // Get user key parameter
    var eventSnapshot = event.data; // Get player data
    var itemsSnapshot = eventSnapshot.child('items'); // Get items data

    itemsSnapshot.forEach(function(itemSnapshot) { // For each item
        var itemKey = itemSnapshot.key; // Get item key
        var itemData = itemSnapshot.val(); // Get item data
    });
});
```

[Here the Firebase Cloud Functions documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events)

Comment: Thanks this was driving me nuts. Follow up question - if there was only ever going to be one child item in the items node, is this still the best way of retrieving it?

Comment: Yes I think, in this function we only use available data without any other database request. Even if there are only one child, the forEach loop is still the best way.